# push view without showing tabbar removes bottom of view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I'm trying to push a view while hiding the uitabbar.
The view which is being pushed have another view inside it which is located in the bottom.
Whenever this view is pushed the uitabbar is not displayed (which is good) but the bottom view I added is not displayed.

how can I hide the tab bar but still show the view I added in the bottom?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm beginning to understand what you mean, but a little specificity would go a long way.  Please post some relevant code, and/or discuss what you're currently doing to try and achieve the effect you want.

Comment: there is no code, the property is being set from the interface designer, if I move the sub view a little bit up it's displayed but that looks like the wrong thing to do.